# How to trim the size of a set in Python

Tags: python, set

I would like to decrease the number of elements in a set. I'm not interested in removing specific elements. Any elements would do, but I would like to remove multiple elements at once. If set.pop() would accept count as parameter it would be great but unfortunatelly it's not the case.

Any ideas? I would like to avoid using pop() in a loop as I find it cumbersome.

Comment: Why dont you use abstractions i.e. write a functions that accepts a count and then uses pop() for that count. Any alternative that you get would be computationally as expensive... so you wont have to repeat pop everytime, you just call your own function with a count...

Answer (score 1):

You can always convert to a list, slice off the end and convert back to a set:

```
s = {1, '2', 'three', 4, (5,), 6}
print(s)

required_length = len(s) - 2
s = set(list(s)[:required_length])

print(s)
```

Output:

```
{1, 4, 'three', 6, (5,), '2'}
{1, 4, 'three', 6}
```